# git2r overwrites function from base

Tags: r, git, merge, r-package

The R package git2r seems to overwrite the meaning of the base::merge function. This breaks the below code.

```
d1 <- c("a", "b")
d2 <- c(1,2)
merge(d1,d2) # This works

# Any call to any git2r function will break the code
git2r::config()

# This does not work anymore.
merge(d1,d2)
base::merge(d1,d2)
```

The error is:

```
Error in discover_repository(path) : 
  Error in 'git2r_repository_discover': 'path' must be a character vector of length one with non NA value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path) : path[1]="a": No such file or directory
2: In normalizePath(path) : path[2]="b": No such file or directory
> traceback()
5: discover_repository(path)
4: repository(repo)
3: lookup_repository(x)
2: merge.character(d1, d2)
1: base::merge(d1, d2)
```

What astonishes me is that explicitly specifying `base::merge` does not solve the issue.
It is probably because the `git2r::merge` function is part of the base namespace, instead of the git2r namespace:

```
git2r::merge
function (x, y, ...) 
UseMethod("merge")
<bytecode: 0x557184940ee0>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

How can I either revert the `base::merge` to the way it was, or avoid git2r overwriting the `base::merge` altogether ?

I tried calling the `git2r::repository` inside of a specific environment, I tried copying the base::merge function prior to the `git2r::repository` call and using it afterwards, I tried to detach the git2r library, but nothing has worked.

Comment: you can use `merge.data.frame` or `merge.default` but this is a problem in the package .. i'm surprised it is allowed on cran with that behaviour

Comment: I've [raised an issue](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r/issues/451)

Comment: @user20650 This works indeed. But as you mention, this is not a very viable solution as it necessitate to change every call of merge in the code, simply because of using git2r. Arguably, base::merge is more "valuable" than git2r::merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the issue elegantly by undoing the S3 method registration for `merge.character` made by the 'git2r' package:

```
rm('merge.character', envir = .BaseNamespaceEnv$.__S3MethodsTable__.)
```

That's all that is required to fix the issue. No need to hack around in the namespace of loaded packages.

Alternatively, perform coercion explicitly (this is what `merge.default` otherwise does):

```
merge(as.data.frame(d1), d1)
```

Comment: Konrad; I'm a bit confused, if only as I've not seen it before (as far as I can remember) but how can loading the the git2r package affect the base R function to the extent that explicitly calling  `base::merge` no longer works?

Comment: @user20650 `base::merge` still works but it is calling in this case `merge.character` and not `merge.default` as you can see in `traceback` in the question.

Comment: @GKi; but there isn't as `base::merge.character` method ... it would normally dispatch to `base::merge.default`. So my confusion how loading `git2r` then manages to *overrule* the explicit use of the `base::` namespace.

Comment: @user20650 It uses `UseMethod("merge")` and this takes the method matching the class as long as it is registrated. This can be seen with `methods(merge)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks a lot for the answer. Just want to add that as GKi mentioned in his answer, in case merge.character from git2r should be used you can still call it directly with git2r:::merge.character.

Answer (score 3):

`git2r` does not *overwrite* `base::merge`. The problem comes that `git2r` defines a method for `merge.character` and `d1` has this `class`, so it is used, as you can see in the output you showed from `traceback`. Method dispatch is done in this case by calling `UseMethod("merge")` in the function `base::merge`.

```
methods(merge)
#[1] merge.data.frame* merge.default*    merge.dendrogram*

d1 <- c("a", "b")
d2 <- c(1,2)

sloop::s3_dispatch(merge(d1,d2))
#  merge.character
#=> merge.default
## As there is no method for character the default will be used

git2r::config()

methods(merge)
#[1] merge.character*      merge.data.frame*     merge.default*       
#[4] merge.dendrogram*     merge.git_branch*     merge.git_repository*

sloop::s3_dispatch(merge(d1,d2))
#=> merge.character
# * merge.default
## Now there is a method for character which will be used
```

But in your case you still want that `merge.default` is used instead of `merge.character`. So you can register afterwards the method `merge.default` for `merge.character` using `.S3method`.

```
.S3method("merge", "character", base::merge.default)

merge(d1,d2)
#  x y
#1 a 1
#2 b 1
#3 a 2
#4 b 2
```

The other methods are not changed. So merge with `git_branch` and `git_repository` will still work.
In case `merge.character` from `git2r` should be use either you call it direct

```
git2r:::merge.character
```

or register it again

```
.S3method("merge", "character", git2r:::merge.character)
```

but then you need, like before, explicitly use `base::merge.default`.

In case `merge.character` is registered, then there would be a warning that it is overwritten by `git2r`.

```
.S3method("merge", "character", base::merge.default)
library(git2r)
#Registered S3 method overwritten by 'git2r':
#  method          from
#  merge.character base
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the comment! I have changed the answer to solve the problem in a different way.